# Как загрузить уже существующую модель (онтологию) из файла?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache

Начну с того, что имею на данный момент: есть уже готовая онтология в формате .rdf, работаю в Android Studio, осваиваю Jena Fuseki именно в студии. Все нужные библиотеки установила.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Передо мной стоит задача - загрузить уже упомянутую существующую модель (онтологию) с файла.
Делаю я это таким вот образом:

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
m.read("C://Users//xeniy//Desktop//DomenEng_04//L01_easy_for_L04.rdf");
m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
```

От студии получаю исключение, которое можно увидеть на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новичком себя именно в программировании назвать не могу, но впервые вижу такое исключение. Метод гугления выдал такой вариант: Проблема в URL. Исходя из этого, код я сменила:

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    try {
        m.read(new File("С:/Users/xeniy/Desktop/DomenEng_04/L01_easy_for_L04.rdf").toURL().toString());
        m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Исключение, конечно, сменилось, вот только оно меня завело в тупик еще сильнее, чем предыдущее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как, все просто: DoesNotExistException прямо говорит о том, что искомый файл не существует или не найден. Вот только файл в папке точно есть, и он вполне себе открывается, а значит - существует.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, кому не сложно, ведь Apache Jena для меня пока что - область новая.